# expected identifier or '(' before 'return'

Tags: c

I am writing an algorithm that draws random numbers from 1 to 60 in which there will be 6 numbers drawn being none repeated, however, I have the following error "expected identifier or '(' before 'return'" and as I am new to programming I could not find the problem. if you can help me would greatly appreciate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int numeroRandomicoNaoRepetido(int sorteioMega[6]) {
    
    int numeroSorteado;
    int x;
    
    for (x = 0; x <= 6; x++) {
        srand(time(NULL));
        numeroSorteado = rand();
    }
    return numeroSorteado;
}

int main()
{
    int sorteioMega[6];
    int x;

    for ( x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        sorteioMega[x] = numeroRandomicoNaoRepetido(sorteioMega);
    }
    printf("Numeros sorteados de 1 a 60 da Mega Sena\n");
    for (x = 0; x < 6; x++)
    {
        if (sorteioMega[x] <= 60) {
            printf("%i ,", sorteioMega[x]); 
        } else {
            numeroRandomicoNaoRepetido(sorteioMega);
            }
        }
        
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This is the code.

The program was supposed to draw 6 numbers from 1 to 60.

Comment: Make sure all your braces have the matching braces. This should be very easy to do, since you've indented the code properly.

Comment: You have an extra `}` before `return` in `main()`.

Comment: You have extra `}` in your `for/if/else` nested construct. Your IDE could help you find it.

Comment: If you would use a better indentation style, you would immediately spot this problems. Align the `{` with the `}` so they are on the same column (or the same line for very short blocks).

Comment: And this is why K&R brace style is rubbish :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is not aligned properly, there is an extra `}` before the `return` statement, hence this statement appears at the global scope which is incorrect.

The error message is confusing, a quality of implementation issue.

Note also these remarks:

- `srand(time(NULL));` should be called only once to initialize the pseudo random number generator.  As coded, you will very likely get 6 identical numbers.
- function `numeroRandomicoNaoRepetido` should store the number into `sorteioMega[x]` in the loop, and verify that the number is not already there. Furthermore this function should take the range as an argument and draw the numbers in the range, decreasing it at each iteration.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) {
    int sorteioMega[6];
    int max = 60;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        /* get a random number such that 0 <= x < max */
        int numeroSorteado = rand() % max;
        /* adjust random number */
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
            if (numeroSorteado >= sorteioMega[i])
                numeroSorteado++;
        }
        sorteioMega[x] = numeroSorteado;
        /* reduce range */
        max--;
    }
    printf("Numeros sorteados de 1 a 60 da Mega Sena\n");
    for (int x = 0; x < 6; x++) {
        printf("%i ", sorteioMega[x] + 1); 
    }
    printf("\n"); 
    return 0;
}
```